# "Буран крутит швыряет снегом и высвистывает и заливается жутким воем": расстановка запятых

Tags: пунктуация, сказуемые

Заинтересовало [предложение](https://ege.yandex.ru/russian/question/A23/2/) в "Яндекс-ЕГЭ" по русскому:

> Буран крутит швыряет снегом и высвистывает и заливается жутким воем.

Нужно ли здесь ставить запятые во всех возможных позициях:

> Буран крутит, швыряет снегом, и высвистывает, и заливается жутким воем.
>
> *("Запятая ставится между всеми однородными членами предложения и в том случае, когда только часть их имеет впереди себя повторяющиеся союзы", [РусЯз.ру](http://www.rusyaz.ru/pr/pz03.html), "Запятая между однородными членами предложения")*

Или можно счесть "швыряет снегом и высвистывает" парной группой:

> Буран крутит, швыряет снегом и высвистывает, и заливается жутким воем.
>
> *("Запятая ставится между парными группами, на которые могут распадаться однородные члены предложения (внутри таких пар не ставится)", там же)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильный вариант: Буран крутит, швыряет снегом,/ и высвистывает,/ и заливается жутким воем.

Здесь первая смысловая группа: крутит (снегом), швыряет снегом.

Швыряет снегом и высвистывает - неверное объединение, действия не связаны друг с другом.